# clip-path with border intact using pure css

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I need to create cut corners, but at the same time the `border` of the shape in the places of the cut should be preserved, I tried to do this using `clip-path`, but I got a rectangle with cut corners and the `border` was cut together with them.

```css
.bottominfo {
  bottom: 1.9%;
  left: 5.7%;
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 2, 0.1);
  border: 1px solid #FF003C;
  position: absolute;
  clip-path: polygon(7% 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 93% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 30%);
  width: 50vw;
  height: 11vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="bottominfo"></div>
```

Comment: I assume that the color of the contour itself can be applied to the clip path, but I don't know how to do this

Comment: By "contour" do you mean the `border`?

Comment: yes exactly border

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to add a wrapper `div` and use another `clip-path` to make the `border`. Essentially what this does is mimic a `border`.

First, set the wrapper `div` with the `background-color` of the desired `border-color`. Then use the same `clip-path` on this new div and specify an `inset` value which will determine your `border-width`.

```css
/* Center Demo */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bottominfo {
  background-color: #fddde6;
  position: absolute;
  inset: 1px; /* border width */
  clip-path: polygon(7% 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 93% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 30%);
}

.bottominfo-wrapper {
  background-color: #FF003C;
  position: relative;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 11vw;
  clip-path: polygon(7% 0, 100% 0, 100% 30%, 100% 70%, 93% 100%, 30% 100%, 0 100%, 0% 30%);
}
```

```html
<div class="bottominfo-wrapper">
  <div class="bottominfo"></div>
</div>
```

**Note:** this will not work with your `rgba` `background-color` because it cannot have an `opacity` of `.1`. So instead I used a `hex` that is the same color.

Comment: thanks for the help, but why not use div instead ::before

Comment: @GLobeasd Because it won't work. It will still be clipped by the `clip-path`...